# What is this mountable adjustable clamp for a pipe called?

Tags: hardware

I am looking for the terminology that I can use in order to find one of these clamps to buy online. I can mount it on wood and then tighten it to keep a pipe in place.

[image: Mountable clamp]

Comment: I have never seen one with the bolt through the back. It could be that it was normal "U strap" and someone drilled it and added the bolt.  There a plethora of pipe hangers or pipe support hangers or pipe clamps.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pipe+clamp+hanger&t=ffsb&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: google `wood to steel pipe clamp` and look at the pictures .... you'll see one that is very similar

Comment: @jsotola  You ought to type this up as an answer and post the picture.

Comment: @JACK the answer would make this a shopping question, because it appears that there may be only one manufacturer and the name of the part is proprietary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe grip tie is the term used by Simpson for [PGT® Pipe Grip Ties®](https://www.strongtie.com/fences_decksandfences/pgt_productgroup_wcc/p/pgt) which are used to attach a wood fence to a metal pipe support.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a field retro fit. A larger clamp than was needed and a two bolt holes drilled in it to make it fit. I have never seen one like this before and I've put up a lot of pipe. There are many pipe clamps that have rubber bushings in them to keep them from hitting the walls.

Comment: Most strut clamps are plain galvanized , very rare to see rubber on a strap, there are plastic ones more often used with hydraulics , I don’t use those often because of cost, but I agree with home made and I have seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

To tell the truth that looks home made to me but it is a pipe strap / clamp. Pro’ s usually use strut clamps , like kindorf, uni strut or power strut.  I said home made because of the hole on the top under the bolt, the strap is not flat to the surface on the bottom.  I would use 1/2” strut channel and an appropriate rigid or universal clamp. We use these in very large numbers in industry but some residential sparky’s save a few $$$ and bend them out of metal strapping. Your example is better than plumbers tape ... galvanized strip with holes ... used in a loop or similar manner.